# File permission while saving a html to server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have  a problem , I want to save a html file in directory using asp.net .
But when i try to do so , 
I got a security exception as follow .

```
7/10/2012 12:03:54 AM,http://www.teddytank.com/admin/AddNewsLetter.aspx?  
      nid=3,System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the     
file   'D:\hosting\7837152\html\ne\newsletter06_07_2012_T_37.html' because it is being 
used by    another process.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileInfo.Delete()
at Admin_AddNewsLetter.Submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
7/10/2012 12:04:45 AM,http://www.teddytank.com/admin/AddNewsLetter.aspx?      
nid=3,System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '
 D:\hosting\7837152\html\ne\newsletter06_07_2012_T_37.html' because it is being used by
another process.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileInfo.Delete()
at Admin_AddNewsLetter.Submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Please help. thanx in advance.

Comment: Can we see your file-writing code?

Comment: Error states "because it is being used by another process": are you sure nothing else is using that file?

Answer (score 0):

Your file is being in use by another process, that says it all, you must check who is using the file, that is if you have the html file opened in another application, also make sure you closed your StreamWriter or Filestream (eg yourstreamwriter.close()), if not you will get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the application pool